# How To Make A Custom Google Map Marker A Hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, hyperlink, frame

I'm not entirely sure if this is possible.

I'm setting up a site for rental trailers and they want the site to open with a Google map as the whole screen,  and the trailers' GPS coordinates as blips on the map.(that's still in the works, but not a problem). i have one blip right now and its just for testing at the moment. What i want to do is make the Google map blip a hyperlink that once clicked will open a frame over the map that gives information about the trailer.

This is my Javascript

```
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
  <script>
  function initialize() {
    var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
    var map_options = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.25, -100),
      zoom: 7,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    } ;

    var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);

    var point       =       new google.maps.LatLng(47, -100);
    var marker  =       new google.maps.Marker ({
        position: point,    
        map: map,
        icon: 'PointMarkerON.png'

    })
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


  </script>
```

This is my HTML

```
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<a href="Site1.php" onclick='marker' target="home"></a> 
<iframe src="" width="1250" height="1000" frameborder="1" name="home"></iframe>
```

Again if it's not possible, letting me know would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want the marker to do something on a click, add a 'click' [event listener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events) to it. [example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
google.maps.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
  iframeElement.src = 'Site1.php';
});
```

Comment: thanks! your help waasn't exactly right but it got me on the right track. for the record i had to id my frame and then put this code in:                                    **google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
  document.getElementById("home").src = 'Site1.php';**
  });

Comment: Yes. I didn't want to specify which way you got that Node. You could do `document.formName.elementName.src = 'Site1.php'` as well as a number of other ways. Of course, that assumes you are using a form, which I don't recommend. AJAX. AJAX. AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe InfoWindow(), is this what you want
[here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple)